# How to send ctrl key press with Auto Hotkey

Tags: autohotkey, ctrl

I am trying to map a mouse button to mimic a single press of a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key on the keyboard. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> is used in a game I am playing to toggle displaying some extra info on the screen)

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to actually send the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key:

```
RButton::
    Send ^
Return
```

If I do like this and send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then it works (for the purposes of my game), which leads me to believe that the `^` only actually gets sent if it has another key to accompany it.

```
RButton::
    Send ^c
Return
```

I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation that supports my theory. I am wondering if any one knows whether my hunch is correct and/or of a way that I can send just the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Send {LControl} or {RControl} depending on what key you wish to send.